# Angular 5 component. Organize editing only the one field

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

How to edit only one field from many?

Here is code:

```
<div *ngIf="count > 0">
<div *ngFor="let prop of propertyList;">
  <p>{{prop}}</p>
</div>
<button (click)="switchFlag(prop)">Edit</button>
<div *ngIf="editFlag; then selectProperty else emptyTemplate"></div>

<ng-template #selectProperty>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Select property">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let prop of getProps(selectProperty); let j = index" [value]="prop">
        {{ prop }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #emptyTemplate>

</ng-template>
```

In result will be something like this:

Property 1   [Edit Button] 
Property 2   [Edit Button]
Property 3   [Edit Button]
Property 4   [Edit Button]
Property 5   [Edit Button]

And how organize editing for instance only for the third property. At the moment I tried to attach click event button, but on click, each property switched for editing.

Comment: Do you mean too put your button inside your ngFor div?

Comment: Add a `*ngIf="count=3"` and do what you need inside it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3309109/artm: yes